# How to user "Discrete" object in openai-gym environments?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am trying to create a Q-Learning agent for a openai-gym "Blackjack-v0" environment. I am trying to get the size of the observation space but its in a form a "tuples" and "discrete" objects.

All I want is to return the size of the "discrete" object. When I print "env.observation_space[0]", it returns "Discrete(32)". I've found the class on github (https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/discrete.py), but nothing is showing how to return the integer "32" or even the value at say "env.observation_space[0][5]".

Is there other functions I can use to return the size of the "discrete" object, and the value itself at a certain index?

Here is some code:

```
print(state_size[0]) # Discrete(32)
# I want it to print 32, not Discrete(32)
print(state_size[1]) # Discrete(11)
# I want it to print 11, not Discrete(11)
print(state_size[2]) # Discrete(2)
# I want it to print 2, not Discrete(2)

print(q_table[state_size[0][0]]) # TypeError: 'Discrete' object does not support indexing 
# I want to return the value of the "Discrete" object
```

Comment: Are you looking for env.observation_space.n?

Comment: No, more about the understanding of how to retrieve information from a "Discrete" object

Comment: Just Use this: ```action_size = env.action_space.n        
                         And  state_size = env.observation_space.n
``` This helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use the attribute `n` of Discrete object.

Example:

```
env.observation_space[0].n >> 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'seed' function, like this:

```
action_space = Discrete(10)
print (action_space.seed(4))
```

And it will return the action_space[4], and it is a list. You can try action_space.seed(4)[0]

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the attribute nA of the env object.

Example:

```
env.nA >> 32
```

The env object also has attribute nS - gives number of states.